# (Reference) Does a ring's grading commute with the formation of fractions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, localization, graded-rings

**Question:**

> Given a graded integral domain, when one forms the corresponding field of fractions, does the resulting field of fractions have a grading "compatible" with the original field of fractions?

If it is true, I imagine the proof is long and tedious, so please don't feel obligated to include or copy the proof here. A pointer to a reference containing the proof will be sufficient for an answer.

**Example:**
I am not sure how to state the result more precisely. Hopefully the following example clarifies.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, consider a projective variety $V \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(k)$, then $V$ corresponds to a homogeneous prime ideal $I$. Therefore the ring $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]/I$ is a graded integral domain. Moreover, the following isomorphism holds $$k[x_0, \dots, x_n]/I \cong \bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^{\infty} \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d}$$ where $R_d$ is the additive subgroup of $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ consisting of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ (i.e. the $R_d$ form the grading of $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$), and I believe it is meant to be understood that the direct sum is an external direct sum.

Because the quotient ring given above is an integral domain (since $I$ is a prime ideal), we can form the field of fractions of this ring, denote it by $$\mathscr{F}\left( 
\bigoplus\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d} \right) \,.$$ If we denote the set (and, I believe, additive group) of all fractions whose numerator and denominator consist both of elements of $\frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d}$ by $\mathscr{F}(\frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d})$, then does one have the following:

> $$\mathscr{F}\left( 
> \bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^{\infty} \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d} \right) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^{\infty} \mathscr{F}\left( \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d} \right) \quad ? $$

The right-hand side is the definition which was given in [my textbook](http://bookstore.ams.org/stml-66) for the field of functions of $V$, $\mathscr{K}_V$. A problem asked me to verify that $\mathscr{K}_V$ was a field. Since the fractions (localization?) of an integral domain is always a field, it is easy for me to verify that the left-hand side is a field, so that if the desired isomorphism actually holds, then I would have a quick and elegant argument that $\mathscr{K}_V$ is a field. As it stands, I was able to verify that it was a field by checking all of the axioms one by one, but I am still curious to know whether the more elegant approach could be justified.

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible with the original field of fractions"?

Comment: @user26857 Would you like me to try to find another example? I only know how to make the statement precise in the context of the example I gave, but I can try to find another example somewhere.

Comment: I didn't read your example. Just tried to figure out what the highlighted part could mean.

Comment: @user26857 I edited the post to highlight the question as stated in the example. I apologize for not being able to be more precise -- this is a large part of why I don't know whether the result is true, since I don't even know how to state it properly. $\mathscr{F}$ stands for fraction, sometimes also field.

Comment: I don't think your question should be asked on the base of an example. You could start with an arbitrary graded domain and perform the construction from the example (without referring to it).

Comment: @user26857 I agree with you, and I would do that if I knew how to do that, but I don't know how to do that. What $$\mathscr{F}\left(\frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d}\right) $$ means in the context of the example is pretty clear (fractions where the numerator and denominator are homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$, modulo the obvious equivalence relation), but I have no idea how to generalize it. Is there even such a thing as the fractions/localization of an abelian group?

Comment: I have some doubts about $\mathcal F(R_d/I\cap R_d)$: is this an abelian group as it is required by the definition of a graded ring?

Comment: @user26857 No, you're right, it isn't. The sum of two such fractions will be in $\mathscr{F}(\frac{R_{2d}}{I \cap R_{2d}})$. I.e., not just multiplication but also addition satisfies $X_d + X_e \subseteq X_{d+e}$. Now I have no idea what I am asking; maybe I should just close/delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields almost never have interesting natural gradings.  In fact, any $\mathbb{Z}$-graded field must be concentrated in degree $0$.  To prove this, suppose $K$ is a field with a grading which is not concentrated in degree $0$ and let $x\in K$ be some homogeneous element of nonzero degree (say, degree $d>0$).  Write $(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{i=m}^n y_i$ where $y_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$ and $y_m$ and $y_n$ are nonzero.  Then since $(1+x)y=1$, all the homogeneous parts of $(1+x)y$ in nonzero degrees must be $0$.  But the homogeneous part of $(1+x)y$ in degree $m$ is just $1\cdot y_m=y_m\neq 0$, which is a contradiction.  (More generally, a similar argument shows any unit in a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded integral domain must be homogeneous.)

In your example, the equation $$\mathscr{F}\left( 
\bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^{\infty} \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d} \right) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^{\infty} \mathscr{F}\left( \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d} \right)$$ is very false.  First of all, the sets on the right-hand side have nontrivial intersection, so you can't take an internal direct sum of them.  For instance, if $f\in R_d$, then $f/f\in \mathscr{F}\left( \frac{R_d}{I \cap R_d} \right)$ but also $f/f=1/1\in \mathscr{F}\left( \frac{R_0}{I \cap R_0} \right)$.  Second of all, the sets on the right-hand side may not even be subgroups, since typically a sum of two fractions of homogeneous elements of degree $d$ will be a fraction of homogeneous elements of degree $2d$, not of degree $d$.  Third, the sum of the sets on the right-hand side is typically not the entire fraction field.  For instance, if $I=0$, the fraction field contains $x_i$ for $i=0,\dots,d$ but the sum of the sets on the right hand side does not.

Comment: This answer makes very clear for me how my entire notion of a grading in the function field $\mathscr{K}_V$ is entirely false. I appreciate it. As a follow-up question (since my book doesn't address the issue), am I right to think that $\mathscr{K}_V$ can be formed as the field of fractions of the quotient ring $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]/I$? I don't need a proof now -- hopefully, once I finish with the book and start working through the exercises in Atiyah, MacDonald, I will figure out how to prove it (if it's even true) myself.

Comment: All my book says about the issue is that the elements of the ring $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ aren't (well-defined) functions on $\mathbb{P}^n$ but that the elements of $\mathscr{K}_V$ are. Which is of course correct, useful, and insightful in its own right, but doesn't really elucidate any algebraic relationship between the two objects. Since the analogous objects in the case of affine varieties _do_ are related by the process of forming the field of fractions, I would be somewhat confused and surprised if they weren't so related in the projective case.

Comment: No, $\mathscr{K}_V$ is typically smaller than the field of fractions.  This is what the last example I gave is about--if $I=0$, then $\mathscr{K}_V$ is just  rational functions whose numerators and denominators have the same degree, but the field of fractions is all rational functions.  In general $\mathscr{K}_V$ is a subfield of the field of fractions, consisting of exactly the elements which do give well-defined functions on $V$.

Comment: Sorry for missing the point of your last example -- I thought it was just that in that case the field of fractions is isomorphic to $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ -- I didn't put two and two together to realize that also implied the answer to my question. So is there no way to construct $\mathscr{K}_V$ algebraically from the polynomial ring $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$?

Comment: As far as I know that's correct.  You need to use not just the ring itself but also its grading.